# upi:// changing to https:// in wp editor

Tags: anchor, shortcode, upi

I am trying to use a upi:// link in  of a page.
If I write the link as it is, like  it works fine.
However I need to get a parameter from a shortcode to the "tn" parameter of upi://

At that point, upi:// changes to https://

Where am I going wrong?
I have set class="upi-pay1" as well. Please help.

My shortcode works fine, when I "echo" from outside  it shows the link fine.
It is only in  tag , upi:// changes to https://